# {"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, binance

I'm trying to change initial leverage on my account.

```
import time
import json
import urllib
import hmac, hashlib
import requests

from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

class Binance():

    methods = {
            #futures
            'futuresExchangeInfo': {'url': 'fapi/v1/exchangeInfo', 'method': 'GET', 'private': False, 'futures': True},
            'futuresKlines': {'url': 'fapi/v1/klines', 'method': 'GET', 'private': False, 'futures': True},
            'MarkPrice': {'url': '/fapi/v1/premiumIndex', 'method': 'GET', 'private': False, 'futures': True},
            'futuresCreateOrder':      {'url': 'fapi/v1/order', 'method': 'POST', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'QueryOrder':      {'url': 'fapi/v1/order', 'method': 'GET', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'ChangeLeverage': {'url': '/fapi/v1/leverage', 'method': 'POST', 'private':True, 'futures':True},
            'futuresAccount':      {'url': 'fapi/v2/account', 'method': 'GET', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'futuresBalance':      {'url': 'fapi/v2/balance', 'method': 'GET', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'futuresSymbolPriceTicker': {'url': 'fapi/v1/ticker/price', 'method': 'GET', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'futuresOrderInfo': {'url': 'fapi/v1/order', 'method': 'GET', 'private': True, 'futures': True},
            'futuresCancelOrder':      {'url': 'fapi/v1/order', 'method': 'DELETE', 'private': True, 'futures': True}
    }
    
    def __init__(self, API_KEY, API_SECRET):
        self.API_KEY = API_KEY
        self.API_SECRET = bytearray(API_SECRET, encoding='utf-8')
        self.shift_seconds = 0

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            kwargs.update(command=name)
            return self.call_api(**kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def set_shift_seconds(self, seconds):
        self.shift_seconds = seconds
        
    def call_api(self, **kwargs):

        command = kwargs.pop('command')
        api_url = 'https://fapi.binance.com/' + self.methods[command]['url']
        #api_url = 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com:443/' + self.methods[command]['url']
        payload = kwargs
        headers = {}
        
        payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
        
        if self.methods[command]['private']:
            payload.update({'timestamp': int(time.time() + self.shift_seconds - 1)})
            payload_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf-8')
            sign = hmac.new(
                key=self.API_SECRET,
                msg=payload_str,
                digestmod=hashlib.sha256
            ).hexdigest()

            payload_str = payload_str.decode("utf-8") + "&signature="+str(sign) 
            headers = {"X-MBX-APIKEY": self.API_KEY}

        if self.methods[command]['method'] == 'GET':
            api_url += '?' + payload_str
        response = requests.request(method=self.methods[command]['method'], url=api_url, data="" if self.methods[command]['method'] == 'GET' else payload_str, headers=headers)
        if 'code' in response.text:
            print(response.text)
        return response.json()


bot = Binance(
    API_KEY='',
    API_SECRET=''
)

account=bot.futuresAccount()
cl=bot.ChangeLeverage(symbol='BTCUSDT',leverage=2)
```

When I send timestamp in data I get this error:
{"code":-1102,"msg":"Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."}.
futuresAccount() works fine, but not ChangeLeverage(). I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

ref: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#change-initial-leverage-trade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

time.time() will give you seconds from the epoch, Binance expects milliseconds.

So generally speaking it should be in the form of int(time.time()*1000).

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#endpoint-security-type